# Critique my proof of: Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Then $A \times B = B \times A \iff A = \emptyset, B = \emptyset,$ or $A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Critique my proof on correctness, structure, etc.

*Proof*.

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $A \times B = B \times A$ and let $P = (x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $A \times B$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $A \neq \emptyset$, $B \neq \emptyset$, and $A \neq B$. By definition of cartesian product, $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, and because $A \times B = B \times A$, $\ x \in B$ and $y \in A$. Because $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements and the definition of subset, it follows that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so $A = B$. This is a contradiction, so we can conclude that if $A \times B = B \times A$, then either $A = \emptyset$, $B = \emptyset$, or $A = B$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $A = \emptyset$, $B = \emptyset$, or $A = B$.

**Case #1**

Let $A = \emptyset$. Then $\emptyset \times B = \emptyset = B \times \emptyset$, so $A \times B = B \times A$.

**Case #2**

Let $B = \emptyset$. Then $A \times \emptyset = \emptyset = \emptyset \times A$, so $A \times B = B \times A$.

**Case #3**

Let $A = B$. $A \times B = A \times A = B \times A$, so $A \times B = B \times A$.

$\therefore$ Because all cases have been exhausted, we can conclude that if $A = \emptyset$, $B = \emptyset$, or $A = B$, then $A \times B = B \times A$.

I feel like this proof is too long and that there may be some objection to the claim that "$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements".

Comment: I think that the forward direction can just be proven directly without the need of a contradiction

Comment: @wjmccann I agree, but I was concerned about extending my proof by having to account for the $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \emptyset$ cases. I figured if I did it by contradiction, I wouldn't have to since I'm assuming $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the left-to-right direction, you cannot start by letting $P$ be an arbitrary element of $A \times B$, because you are not proving a statement of the form "for all $P$ in $A \times B,\ \ldots$."  Your strategy was to prove $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so that means your proof should have looked like this:  "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. (Proof of $x \in B$ goes here.)  Therefore $A \subseteq B$.  Now let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $B$.  (Proof of $y \in A$ goes here.)  Therefore $B \subseteq A$."

You can tell that there is something wrong with your proof because your proof never used the assumption that $A \ne \varnothing$ and $B \ne \varnothing$, but those assumptions are necessary.  If you fill in the proof outline above, you will find that you need to use those assumptions to complete the proof.

Comment: I knew that was odd, but I just accepted that I didn't have to use $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$. I see where I went wrong now.